# Is it better to submit a new research grant proposal or an extension of previous work?

Tags: publications, research-process, funding, research-topic

When submitting a research proposal for a funding agency, I heard two different pieces of advice from principal investigators that have won several awards. The first suggestion is to submit a proposal that is directly related to the PI work and consider that as a preliminary result. The second piece of advice was to submit something totally new which might extend the boundaries of science. I wonder if there are any general recommendations for research proposals that would increase the chance of being funded.

Comment: Can you clarify what sort of proposal you refer to? Is this for an individual fellowship?

Comment: @BryanKrause proposals to federal or private funding agencies

Comment: Yes but *for what*? Proposals to "federal or private" doesn't really narrow it down at all.

Comment: @BryanKrause to fund students to do research

Comment: ...sigh...okay, maybe I'm just being ridiculously pedantic here and I suppose no one is required to respond to any comments on their post, but I feel like you're being extremely unhelpful and even obtuse. You mention a "PI" which makes it sound like you're working under a senior person. Are you talking about a grant for your own lab? Or a new grant for a lab you work in? Is this a grant where you are the primary responsible person for the grant, or are you contributing to a grant proposal that is officially under the PI? Is this a "new" stream or replacing one expiring? Budget? Field?

Comment: @BryanKrause Yes, grant for my own lab. I don't have an estimate for the budget. It is a STEM-related field.

Answer (score 3):

There is no one-size-fits all answer. The key factors to consider are: (1) alignment to the funder's mission and (2) credibility.

**Alignment to the funder's mission.** Different funding agencies have different motivations. Some have a particular capability gap (whether mundane or extraordinary) and want to fund the group most likely to fix it. Some routinely fund well-established university groups and just want to see progress. Others specifically exist to fund high-risk, high-reward endeavors. Whether to propose "incremental" advances based on past research or "revolutionary" advances will depend on the funder's needs.

**Credibility.** Even for high-risk programs, successful proposals will usually provide a basis of confidence that the proposed idea will be successful (i.e., simply writing down some crazy idea to "extend the boundaries of science" will not be enough). In some cases, this basis of confidence could be the involvement of the proposal authors themselves (due to their publication record or performance on other programs). In other cases, this could be that a proof-of-concept of the proposed idea was already carried out and gave good results.

Comment: "performance on other programs" like what?

Comment: Past work in the same domain, or for the same funder.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no such general recommendations.

> The second piece of advice was to submit something totally new which might extend the boundaries of science.

Some funders give money for research with a high risk to fail.

> The first suggestion is to submit a proposal that is directly related to the PI work and consider that as a preliminary result.

Others want to be more on the safe side. It totally depends on where/in which program you apply for funding.

Comment: "Some funders give money for research with a high risk to fail." such as?

Comment: DARPA is probably the quintessential example. But even on a high-risk DARPA program, successful proposals will have to find the right balance between proposing revolutionary ideas and having a realistic chance of realizing these ideas.